# Insert test data for each unit test for SQL Server 2008 Database Project

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-project

I have Visual Studio Premium and I'm using the test projects that come with it for my database. I'd like to be able to insert test data just before a unit test is run for each test in my Visual studio SQL Server 2008 database project. Do I do this right in the test itself or is there some other way to do a Data Generation Plan for each unit test? Also I'd like to be able to reuse the test data sometimes in different unit tests.

**EDIT: More detail:**
I have a stored procedure which matches buyers and sellers in a fake stock program that will be run in a job. I need the test because there are so many different combinations of data that can be fed into the SP that I don't want to lose track of. The SP takes a chunk of buyers and WHILE loops through them and one by one matches them up with sellers. Hopefully that gives enough detail...

Answer (score 1):

In general I wouldn't call any test that requires actual database data to be a unit test.  Rather I'd consider it to be an integration test.

My nitpicking aside, you can mark your setup and teardown methods with the attributes [TestInitialize] and [TestCleanup] in MSTest.  These will run before and after each test.  If you want to setup data for the full test run then you can use [ClassInitialize] and [ClassCleanup].

```
[TestInitialize]
public void MyTestInitialize(){
  // Build needed data for my test
 ...
}

[TestCleanup]
public void MyTestCleanup(){
  // Clean up my test data after my test
  ...
}
```

Comment: Wasn't really what I was looking for but please see my edits to see why.